# Arrange data in a two-way table

Tags: r

I have a question regarding data formatting.
I have a data. frame that looks like this:

> ```
>    Ontology     Value      Cluster
>       A          2.4          C1
>       A          2.1          C2
>       B          1.3          C0
>       C          1.4          C3
>       A          0.2          C3
>       B          1.6          C4
>       D          0.4          C1
>       D          1.2          C3
>       G          0.2          C0
>       A          9.7          C4
> ```

Is there a quick way to get the following?

```
    Ontology   C0     C1    C2     C3    C4
       A       na     2.4   2.1    0.2   9.7
       B       1.3    na     na     na   1.6
       C       na     na     na    1.4    na
       D       na     0.4    na    1.2    na
       G       0.2    na     na     na    na
```

Comment: have you checked https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_wider.html,

Comment: or you can simply do `X = as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(Value ~ Ontology+Cluster,data=df)) ; X[X==0] = NA`, assuming `df` is your dataframe

Comment: Okkk thank you for the suggestion but the point is that there are "na" in my data

Comment: `tidyr::pivot_wider(df, names_from = Cluster, values_from = Value)`

Comment: Thank you Ronak. It is fantastic! It works!